# When I am running a deployment command on my pipeline us it fails saying MSI is not configured properly

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-blob-storage, azure-cli

I am deploying a static react web app into azure static website (blob storage) using the command

While doing so I am doing it through Azure CLI (Inline command).

```
az storage blob upload-batch -s ./ -d '$web' \
--account-name <storage_acct_name> \
--account-key <storage_acct_key>
```

This command gives me an error

```
2022-11-17T08:27:29.5243851Z ERROR: Failed to connect to MSI. Please make sure MSI is configured correctly.
2022-11-17T08:27:29.5244667Z Get Token request returned http error: 400, reason: Bad Request
2022-11-17T08:27:29.5274714Z ##[error]Error Code: [1]
2022-11-17T08:27:29.5283948Z ##[error]Error: Azure login failed using Managed Service Identity
2022-11-17T08:27:29.5285668Z ##[error]Script failed with error: ERROR: Failed to connect to MSI. Please make sure MSI is configured correctly.
```

What could be possible solution to get over this issue.

Comment: Hi @Varad, is the answer below to log in with credential helps you? If so, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried in my environment and successfully deployed **`static web app`** in **`$Web`**.

Before running the command make sure you have logged in with current credentials:

```
az login --tenant xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx”
```

**Command:**

```
 az storage blob upload-batch -d '$web' -s < path > --account-name <account name > --account-key "<account key>
```

**Console:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

1. [azure - Configuration of Managed Service Identity(MSI) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280460/configuration-of-managed-service-identitymsi) for pipeline problems.
2. [Getting token from Cloud Shell intermittently fails with 400 Client Error: Bad Request · Issue #11749 · Azure/azure-cli · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11749#issuecomment-570975762)